# Dell vostro 2520 switch off bluetooth

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth

I've got vostro 2520. The thing that annoys me is that by default it switches on bluetooth  as addition to wifi & i have to switch it off after every reboot :(
Can i save the state switched of for bluetooth as a default? this is to prolong battery life.
I didn't find an answer to this googling. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open `/etc/rc.local` in a text editor, e.g.

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
   ```
2. Just *above* the `exit 0` line, add a line

   ```
   rfkill block all
   ```
3. Save the file and close the editor.
4. Reboot and notice Bluetooth and WiFi are switched off (as well as other radios - see below).

For other readers who want to script radios individually, it's possible to replace `all` with `wifi` (same as `wlan`), `bluetooth`, `uwb` (same as `ultrawideband`), `wimax`, `wwan`, `gps` and `fm`.

---

*Addendum - as OP [edited his answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/251012/2).*

The contents of this in `/etc/rc.local` (complete) works for disabling Bluetooth every boot:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
rfkill block bluetooth
exit 0
```

Comment: so i write `rfkill block bluetooth` to block bluetooth. thanks!